# Cisco ASA 5505 Config -> Text File

Tags: networking, cisco, configuration, cisco-asa, putty

I'm just starting out learning to config Cisco ASA.  My office lent me their old ASA 5505 and I plan to do a factory-reset.  Before I do that, I'd like to backup the config to a text file on the machine I'm connecting to it from.

Right now, I ONLY have the console cable attached and am logged in using PuTTy.  The existing config is pretty big so I'm unable to do a "show run" and then copy/paste (the beginning of the config is cut off).  I also tried using logging in PuTTy but everything is all smushed together.

Is there a way to export the config directly to a text file on my desktop (using Win Server 2008)?

Comment: Problem solved but thought I would add this anyway, "everything is all smushed together" - try changing Session, Logging, Session Logging to "Printable Output" rather than "All Session Output"

Answer (score 2):

- TFTP it off, if you can get IP connectivity to it
- Configure PuTTY to allow more scrollback in the Window options:
  [image: putty]
- ASDM also has an option to give you a copy of the config, with IP connectivity
- Define "smushed" - perhaps it's giving you output with LF line endings?  Try opening it in a better text editor than notepad.

Answer (score 2):

Log into your ASA 5505.
Type `show run` to display the running configuration.

Click the top/left screen icon (in Putty) and select `COPY ALL TO CLIPBOARD`
Open a text editor and paste the output.

The cleaner method is to use tftp, as it will preserve passwords. For basic backup, the above is okay.

If you're planning to use this firewall long-term, I'd recommend acquiring current copies of the ASA software and ASDM (graphical interface). There have been some major changes to the ASA software, and it makes sense to work with the newer versions.

Comment: `more system:running-config` will give you the passwords and keys that are redacted with a `*` in `show running-config`.

Comment: Thank you both!!!
I wound up doing a combo of both of your suggestions; I had to change the scrollback to 5000 to get it all!

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get the full configuration off the ASA is either use `more system:running-config` (as opposed to `show running-configuration`) or to gain IP connectivity to it and copy the configuration to a tftp server. with `copy running-config tftp://my.tftp.server/config.txt`. Any other method will ommit 'sensitive' configuration information, such as pre-shared keys.

To make a local backup of the running configuration you can simply do `copy running-config flash:/config.backup`

Then you can do a `write erase` to clear the current startup  config and `reload` the ASA to start configuring again from scratch.

Comment: Your first statement is wrong. `more system:running-config` will show the config in all of its unsanitized glory.